# PyCharm: How to document :rtype: for function that returns generator

Tags: python, pycharm, generator, docstring

I try to document a `:rtype:` docstring parameter returning a generator of `Node`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """iterate over node children

    :rtype: ???
    """
    for node in self.children.itervalues():
        yield node
```

What `:rtype:` is supposed to be? `generator of Node` doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hint the type of `self.children` using `:type` below it, as described in the [official](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) documentation. This would let you work with this variable everywhere using defined types. Here is an example:

```
class Node(object):
    def foo(self):
        pass


class Iterator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = ''
        """:type: dict[str, Node]"""   # <<< define type of self.children after assigning the value

    def __iter__(self):
        for node in self.children.itervalues():
            yield node


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for node in Iterator():
        node. # <<< type hinting will work here
```

[image]

But if you prefer to set the return type of `__iter__` method, you can do it using next syntax:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """
    :rtype: collections.Iterable[Node]
    """
    for node in self.children.itervalues():
        yield node
```

I would prefer first solution though.

Comment: I didn't know you can do this! Thanks! I tried with `# type: dict[int, Node]` and it works fine. But my position is to use restStructuredTex to generate documentation so I need to states somewhere in the function docstring the returned type.

Comment: @Narann, then you can use second approach, should work as well.